# Por Que Funciona Solo Con Consola?

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap, css3, angular5

Estoy desarrollando esta pagina pero solo cuando abro la consola el vídeo se reproduce si cierro la consola ya no se reproduce.(al abrir la consola conservo el mismo tamaño de pantalla que tengo por si alguien preguntaba)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter,Input  } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeWhile'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-video',
  templateUrl: './video.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./video.component.css']
})
export class VideoComponent implements OnInit  {
  @Input() muted:boolean;
  mobile:boolean
  myVar:boolean = false;
  videos=``

  constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) {
    console.log(window.location.origin)
    this.httpClient.get('/mobile',{responseType: 'json'})
    .subscribe(
      (data:any)=>{
        this.mobile=data.mobile
        if(data.mobile){
          this.videos=``
        }else{
          this.videos=`${window.location.origin}/video`
        }
      }
    )


   }

  

  ngOnInit() {
    
    Observable.interval(1000)
    .takeWhile(() => this.myVar = true)
    .subscribe(i => { 
        // This will be called every 10 seconds until `stopCondition` flag is set to true
    })
  }




}
```

```css
.slider{
    
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center; 
}


.vid {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
}
/* auto change 100%*/
.vid video {
    
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        min-width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        z-index: 1;
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    
      background-size: cover;
      transition: 1s opacity;
    
}

@media screen and (max-device-width: 800px) {
    .slider { 
        background: url(https://scontent.fgdl5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/25552067_552126321790932_1620459106336366433_n.jpg?oh=97214c3f3c4bdf35e8a738c1c3eec8c1&oe=5B1450F5);
        height: 100vh;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center; }
    .vid video{
        display: inline;

        position: static;
        top: auto;
        left: auto;
        min-width: 0px;
        min-height: 0px;

    
      background-size: auto;
      transition: 0s opacity;
    }
    .video{
        display: none;
    }
}

/*******************spiner*********************/


.loader {
    
    border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
    border-top: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    z-index: 2;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    
}

.imgd{
    position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        min-width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        z-index: 2;
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        background-color: black;
      background-size: cover;
      transition: 1s opacity;
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
    <div *ngIf="!mobile" class="vid d-flex  container-fluid justify-content-center align-items-center ">
                
            
        <div class="imgd"  [hidden]="myVar">
        </div>
                <div class="loader" [hidden]="myVar">
                </div>
                    
              
        <video #video [muted]="muted"  play inline autoplay  loop id="bgvid" class="d-none d-sm-none d-md-block  ">
          <source src="{{videos}}" type="video/mp4">
          </video>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="mobile" class="vid d-flex slider container-fluid justify-content-center align-items-center ">
            <div class="imgd"  [hidden]="myVar">
                </div>
                        <div class="loader" [hidden]="myVar">
                        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el valor del atributo `muted`? Chrome no permite autoplay si el vídeo no está en silencio

Comment: Lo que comentas es verdad, el atributo muted esta true y se encuentra en una clase padre

Comment: Lo que noto es que si llega una petición a mi servidor con la consola abierta y sin la consola abierta no llega petición alguna.                              Creo que alli esta el problema